# EAV modelled database schema - query advice

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, entity-attribute-value

I am building a database schema of customers & rather than forever adding columns over time, I would prefer to use the EAV (entity attribute value) Magento-style of having this data stored in other tables and linked up.

My SQL Fiddle will give a better idea of the structure
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a70

In this instance I would want to generate a query that displays all the customers with their relevant information that is stored in the other tables, if for example a customer hasn't got a value for a particular entity it just displays NULL.

e.g My output that I would want to display is as follows:

```
customer_id | first_name |  surname  | profession | club
      1          bob        geldof       singer      NULL
      2         lionel       messi      footballer   barcelona fc
```

Can anyone suggest the most optimised MySQL query to produce this recordset on the basis there could be many more entities or attributes added later on?

Comment: sorry, but `the most optimised MySQL query to produce this recordset` will require that you NOT use EAV.  By using an EAV, you will need a `left join` for each of your result set attribute columns.

Comment: @KM i'd agree, I am just getting into EAV and would like 'get my feet' even if toes do get burned on the way :)

Comment: You're not obliged to LEFT JOIN for every record - but that is probably the optimal solution in terms of performance. Well done for providing a fiddle BTW

Comment: Am I going about it the wrong way - would you recommend a different strategy and not using EAV at all? If so could which, as i'm at struggle to think of another method at the moment although I do see the issues with EAV (no wonder Magento can be so slow sometimes lol)

Comment: EAV's unpopular because, as you've discovered, it's notoriously difficult to work with. However, as long as you set it up to take best advantage of data types, it's vaguely manageable. I mean, look at wordpress.

Comment: +1 for dropping in wordpress lol :P thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of SQL query will produce the table you're looking for, but you will have to generate this query dynamically based on the contents of your 'eav_attribute' table.

As KM said, each attribute requires another LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
  customer_entity.customer_id AS customer_id,
  name.value AS firstname, 
  surname.value AS surname,
  profession.value AS profession,
  club.value AS club
FROM customer_entity
  LEFT JOIN customer_varchar AS name
    ON name.entity_id = customer_entity.customer_id AND name.attribute_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN customer_varchar AS surname
    ON surname.entity_id = customer_entity.customer_id AND surname.attribute_id = 2
  LEFT JOIN customer_varchar AS profession
    ON profession.entity_id = customer_entity.customer_id AND profession.attribute_id = 3
  LEFT JOIN customer_varchar AS club
    ON club.entity_id = customer_entity.customer_id AND club.attribute_id = 4
;
```